# circleci # Unable to parse YAML # mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: android, continuous-integration, circleci-2.0

i need to build my `Android` app, in [CriclCi](https://circleci.com/). I just found a [provided sample](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-android/) which is as below:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/code
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-25-alpha
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
#      - run:
#         name: Chmod permissions #if permission for Gradlew Dependencies fail, use this.
#         command: sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: ./gradlew lint test
      - store_artifacts: # for display in Artifacts: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/artifacts/ 
          path: app/build/reports
          destination: reports
      - store_test_results: # for display in Test Summary: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/collect-test-data/
          path: app/build/test-results
      # See https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deployment-integrations/ for deploy examples
```

But, when i use it, the CircleCi build fails and complains with:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
./gradlew androidDependencies
/bin/bash: ./gradlew: Permission denied
Exited with code 126
```

As a result, i added the below code and try it again:

```
  run:
         name: Chmod permissions
         command: sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
```

This code is recommended by `CCI`, but this time it complains with:

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
# Unable to parse YAML
# mapping values are not allowed here
#  in 'string', line 13, column 16:
#               - run:
#                    ^
# 
# -------
# Warning: This configuration was auto-generated to show you the message above.
# Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect.
false
```

**How can i fix it?**

Answer (score 2):

i got the point, indentation in `yml` file should always remain constant. 
So, the `run` keywords should always be in same column.